# After successfully deleting an item from my database table, my view does not update. (KnockoutJS w/Mapping and jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've tried several different approaches, but I've been unsuccessful in having my view update its contents. My view contains a list of `customers` and a list of `employees`.

This represents what I've tried so far omitting `employees` as its essentially duplicated code.

```
function dbControl() {
    var self=this;
    self.customers = function() { $.ajax(...) }; // returns customers object 
    self.addCustomer = function() { $.ajax(...) };
    self.delCustomer = function() { $.ajax(...) };
}
var DB = new dbControl();

var VM = {};

// Populate the VM
VM.selCustomer = ko.observable();
VM.customers = ko.mapping.fromJS(DB.customers);
VM.addCustomer = function() {
    DB.addCustomer()                // successfully adds to Database
    VM.customers.push();            // push VM.selCustomer() into VM.customers
} 
VM.delCustomer = function() {
    DB.delCustomer()                // succcessfully removes from Database
    VM.customers.remove();          // removes VM.selCustomer() from VM.customers
}

// Knockout Binding
ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

The `data-bind="foreach: customers"` binding works on the webpage just fine and lists all the entries.

All the AJAX calls successfully LIST/ADD/DELETE from the Database properly, but the View does not update after a successful DELETE.

I've tried adding `ko.mapping.fromJS(DB.customers, VM)` to the end of the delete function in the VM as instructed in the [DOCS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):*Then, every time you receive new data from the server, you can update all the properties on viewModel in one step by calling the ko.mapping.fromJS function again*, but no luck.

I've tried adding `VM.customers.valueHasMutated()` to the VM and it still doesn't update.

I've tried creating an interval to run both previous attempts:

```
setInterval(function() {
    VM.customers = [];
    VM.customers = ko.mapping.fromJS(DB.customers);
    VM.customers.valueHasMutated();
}, 1000);
```

Am I structuring this whole project wrong?

Comment: Can you try `$.ajax({url: "yourURl", cache: false});`

Comment: @Degnome tried it, but still no update. Should VM.customers be initialized as an observable array before the mapping?

Also, `async: false` was added/removed. Both unsuccessful.

Comment: From other projects, I've used $.load() to refresh just the list container. Would that still be a reasonable method? I'd like to avoid the potential overhead of making another GET/POST request as KnockoutJS advertises itself to be 'self-view-updating'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after more copy/pasting, I think I've solved my own problem:

The reason the View wasn't updating was because the data coming from the database was never being "re-called".

To fix the problem, within the add/delete functions in the VM, I had to call first the function that pulls the data from the server DB.getCustomers(), then make the ko.mapping.fromJS(DB.customers, {}, VM.customers) call.

```
function dbControl() {
    var self = this;
    getCustomers = function() {
        $.ajax({
            /* URL/TYPE/DATA/CACHE/ASYNC */
            success: function() {
                self.customers = data; // Now, DB.customers == Updated Data!
            }
        }); 
    }
}

var DB = new dbControl();

VM = {};

VM.addCustomer = function() {
    DB.addCustomer()                // successfully adds to Database
    //VM.customers.push(); <------ Remove the redundancy
    DB.getCustomers();              // get the new list from the server
    ko.mapping.fromJS(DB.customers, {}, VM.customers);
} 
VM.delCustomer = function() {
    DB.delCustomer()                // succcessfully removes from Database
    //VM.customers.remove(); <------ Remove the redundancy
    DB.getCustomers();              // get the new list from the server
    ko.mapping.fromJS(DB.customers, {}, VM.customers);
}
```

Comment: Can anyone give me any tips to make this run asynchronously (`async:true`)?  Right now, it has to wait until DB.customers (`async:false`) is populated before the view shows the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
VM.addCustomer = function() {
  DB.addCustomer()                // successfully adds to Database
  VM.customers.push();            // push VM.selCustomer() into VM.customers
} 
VM.delCustomer = function() {
  DB.delCustomer()                // succcessfully removes from Database
  VM.customers.remove();          // removes VM.selCustomer() from VM.customers
}
```

You're not passing anything to `push` or `remove`; those two methods of `observableArray` definitely want arguments. Depending on how the methods of `DB` are written, you may have the same problem with them.

Comment: The snippet I gave is just an example, but yes, I understand what you mean. The .push()/.remove() works as intended, but is there a way to do this with ko.mapping.fromJS alone? The .remove() seems redundant after successfully deleting from the database.